# How to check if given Windows session is shadowed?

Tags: windows-terminal-services

Assume the following scenario:
I log on terminal server with RDP.
Another users connects to my session with "mstsc.exe /shadow:" command. 
I get the message to confirm this access, and I agree.
Then, after a while I would like to check if I'm still shadowed. Or - even terminate shadowing from my session. Is there any way to do it? Any command, WMI query, or so?

Comment: I found out that shadowed sessions has special event semaphore created by RdpSa.exe program. Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285064/how-to-check-if-session-is-being-shadowed-in-windows-terminal-server